# Git Pre release hook: Automatically put release tag in constant file?

Tags: git, githooks

Does GIT support **pre-release** hooks? When I press release in GIT, I would like to put the release tag in a constant file, commit it, and the release it.

Yeah we can do this via tools like Jenkins, but I am working at a client which does not have such "advanced" facilities.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't support pre-release hooks because there is no concept of "release" in git. This a concept at Github (and perhaps other git repository hosting). Github creates a release for every tag.

So your "pre-release hook" could be a script (or a git alias) that puts version (or tag name, or whatever) in a file, adds, commits, creates a tag and pushes to Github.

See as example my prerelease scripts for [SQLObject](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/tree/master/devscripts) and [Cheetah3](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/tree/master/devscripts).